# cakephp 2.x delete not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

im trying to delete a record with following code:

in Controller:

```
    public function delete($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Modelname->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Modelname ungültig'));
    }

    $this->Modelname->id = $id;

    $this->request->onlyAllow('post', 'delete');
    if ($this->Modelname->delete()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Modelname wurde gelöscht.'));
        return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'modelnames', 'action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Modelname wurde nicht gelöscht.'));
}
```

in View:

```
<?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('controller' => 'modelnames', 'action' => 'delete', $id), array('confirm' => 'Soll dieser Eintrag wirklich gelöscht werden?')) ?>
```

Usually this works for me, but now its just refreshing the page without doing anything.. mhh any ideas?

Comment: This sort of question isn't useful or appropriate for Stack Overflow. Check out [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: make sure $id is passing correctly through url ..also try commenting $this->request->onlyAllow('post', 'delete'); line .

Comment: @drmonkeyninja
Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

i cant shrink down the problem more than i posted the problem ;( i'd just like to understand how things work - and i thought this is a minimal problem which i could avoid in the future and get a clear view of WHY it didnt work atm :)

Comment: @ManoharKhadka when i comment out the onlyAllow and change the postLink to a normal link it "works" (but in my eyes a little bit "dirty" ?), so i guess theres a problem with the postLink which i dont get.. :/

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like `onlyAllow` method is deprecated on the CakePHP version
>   you are going through.

`postLink` is working well as it is generating equivalent html for post method.

Well if you need to allow only particular request (post,delete) there you can do following either:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) { // if this is a post request
   if (!$this->Modelname->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Modelname ungültig'));
    }

    $this->Modelname->id = $id;

    if ($this->Modelname->delete()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Modelname wurde gelöscht.'));
        return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'modelnames', 'action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Modelname wurde nicht gelöscht.'));
}
```

Comment: `onlyAllow()` method is not deprecated on CakePHP 2.4,   it start from 2.5.

Comment: @tarikul05 Obviously you are right but still that might be the case..or version might be updated by OP.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple as dumb..

TL;DR version:
Form in Form.... (not working)

long version:
i got a huge view page to work over, where there has been kind of a small formwrapper around a table, which i didnt recognize while debugging that stuff.. (simple select table row - doing stuff with them thing)
in this table we had to push extra placeholderdata which can be deleted at a specific time.. the delete via cake postLink (which generates a form) didnt work as you know.. and you know the rest of the story

sorry for wasting your time, but thanks for the fast helpattempt ! and thanks for the "onlyAllow" tipp :)